# How to properly do tree shaking to reduce bundle size and separate entry point for each cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, tree-shaking

I am using Google Firebase Cloud Functions with TypeScript, and I found out that even though each function is deployed separately, they all share the same bundles and dependencies, even if some functions do not use them nor import them.

In my case, one cloud function uses Redis and others don't. I have 10 functions. All 10 functions actually end up importing redis related code even though they don't import them.

Since all functions share the same entry point, index.js. It currently seems it's impossible to have separate tree-shaken bundles / entry points for each function.

This is very inefficient in terms of bundle size / cold start timing / memory / etc. It also means as I have more and more functions, bundle size will grow for all functions together. It's not scalable.

Is there any way to not share the entry point, index.js, and have completely separate bundles by using bundlers like webpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a different local Firebase working area (with `firebase init`) for each function that should deploy in isolation from the others.  You will have to instruct the CLI not to overwrite the other functions on deployment using the `--only functions:yourFunctionName` to deploy it.

Or, you can deploy function using Cloud tools (gcloud) instead of Firebase tools, but you won't be able to use firebase-functions and its TypeScript bindings.

Or, you can lazily load your modules instead of statically loading them at the global scope of your functions, as described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM&t=4s).

I don't recommend using webpack.  It's not going to be worth your time to get it configured.

Comment: Following the first suggestion, I took the hello world typescript sample from a fresh `firebase init functions`. I changed it to just `import {functions, logger} from "firebase-functions/v1"`. I also npm installed the latest firebase-functions. In the source browser in GCF console, there is no library code at all (i.e. package cache is being used). So I am left to ask: *Does the first suggestion do any tree shaking?* If it did I would expect to see the firebase functions code in the source tree, shaved down a little, or a source bundle to the same effect.

Comment: My guess it that the decision was made to rely on the package cache rather than tree shaking. Given that we see a hard requirement in the documentation to list the cloud functions package in the package.json, it doesn't seem like they want to make it easy to webpack all the libraries [by documenting a packageless triggering scheme]. If we want to cooperate with this framework, then a compromise would be to webpack all application code into separate entry points, but rely on package cache for all npm packages, and then lazy load the application entry points within the function triggers.

Comment: Note, the combined index lazy loaded entries can be dropped by using `codebases`, with one function per code space. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/organize-functions

Answer (score 0):

You might try [better-firebase-functions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-firebase-functions), which solves this elegantly by automatically lazy loading only the function that is currently invoked by checking the environment variable `FUNCTION_NAME` - see https://link.medium.com/4g3CJOLXidb